# Sharing image via React Native 'Share' Component

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm having problem with sharing images in my local device.
In RN package, There has 'Share' Component so that I can share text messages.
But there are no reference to share image not text.

Is there any way to share image?

I don't want to use 3rd party libraries...
They are seems not using android native code.

Comment: Hi, did you find out how to solve this issue? Currently having the same problem

Comment: @DonKanallie No... I found who developed this component, but he said it only can share string.

Answer (score 0):

[This issu](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17682)e suggests that it may be possible with the newer version (0.53) version of react-native, but it's not confirmed yet.

You said that you don't want to use 3rd party libs, but I've been studying this issue and a lot of devs are pointing to [this repository](https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share), just give it a chance.